# What is the best way to pass Kafka Headers in distributed applications?

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, header

Currently my team and me are working in a project where we develop a distributed Kafka processing application. And we want to know how to conveniently pass Kafka Headers through these components.

What does this mean? Please have a look at the following sample image:

[image: sample architecture]

Our `Component A` receives events and generates based on the content a unique Header with metadata information about the event. After processing the result is passed into `Topic A` with the generated Header.

`Component B` and `Component C` receive these events, start processing and write their results into `Topic B` and `Topic C`. These components don't use the generated Headers from `Component A`.

But `Component D` needs it. So `Component B` and `Component C` must receive the header and pass it through.

Our system in the project is a little bit bigger than this example and that's why we questioned ourselves: What is the best way to pass Kafka Headers through these components. Is there an automatic way?

We considered following approaches:

- Don't use Kafka Headers at all and pass the metadata information though the body.
- Usage of interceptors (if that is even possible)

FYI we use Spring Boot.

Thanks in advance,
Michael